# Meteor Up Deployment to Amazon EC (Ubuntu 14.04) not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, meteor, meteor-up

I setup a standard Amazon Micro instance with Ubuntu 14.04, set a sudo user, and basically followed the instructions for Meteor Up. I get this error at the "Invoking deployment process" stage...

```
 -----------------------------------STDERR-----------------------------------
        Warning: Permanently added 'ec2-54-200-136-28.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com,54.200.136.28' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
        npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
        npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fibers
          % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                         Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
        Latest deployment failed! Reverted back to the previous version.
        -----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

        > fibers@1.0.1 install /opt/meteor/tmp/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers
        > node ./build.js
```

am I doing something wrong? I've got port 80 opened in the Amazon EC2 settings and my mup.json file looks like this:

```
{
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "[amazon_IP]",
      "username": "ubuntu",
      "password": "password"
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      //"pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
    }
  ],

  // Install MongoDB in the server, does not destroy local MongoDB on future setup
  "setupMongo": true,

  // WARNING: Node.js is required! Only skip if you already have Node.js installed on server.
  "setupNode": true,

  // WARNING: If nodeVersion omitted will setup 0.10.25 by default. Do not use v, only version number.
  "nodeVersion": "0.10.25",

  // Install PhantomJS in the server
  "setupPhantom": true,

  // Application name (No spaces)
  "appName": "meteor",

  // Location of app (local directory)
  "app": "/home/meteor_apps/thestory",

  // Configure environment
  "env": {
    "PORT": 80,
    "ROOT_URL": "http://54.200.136.28"
  },

  // Meteor Up checks if the app comes online just after the deployment
  // before mup checks that, it will wait for no. of seconds configured below
  "deployCheckWaitTime": 15
}
```

I just set my ROOT_URL to be the Amazon Public IP... not really sure where Meteor uses ROOT_URL env variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a micro instance it takes a bit longer for Meteor up to finish bundling your app. Increase `deployCheckWaitTime` to something like `300` (5 minutes).

Whats happening is Meteor up gives up waiting for it to finish, so you need to increase this timeout.

Also you might want to check the node version, depending on your Meteor version you may need to use  a later version such as 0.10.28 for 0.8.1.2/3. You could try installing it but if you run into trouble you would need to run `mup setup` again or install node manually.

Comment: hmm.. ok, I'll try again, do I need anything in my settings.json file? I didn't touch it and don't even really know why it's there. Also does it matter what appName is? I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around what to put for ROOT_URL..

Comment: @JasonIp give it another go, if there's anything wrong itll complain while deploying, ROOT_URL looks fine if you dont have a domain

Comment: works! thank you sir! well, the plan is eventually to have a domain.. what I plan to do is point a domain at my Amazon micro instance, if I do that, do I need to set the ROOT_URL? If not, when and how, does Meteor use ROOT_URL?

Comment: Meteor uses it to route requests properly, e.g if you use an oauth like facebook login, facebook needs to know where to redirect to once you log in for example. You can change it and redeploy when you get a domain.